# How to `uglyfy` all files from a folder to dest folder using grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a grunt file. at present i have set only one file for src and dest. it works well. how to i set this for all js file from a folder to dest folder?

here is my config file :

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({


        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


        uglify: {
          options: {
            banner: '/*\n <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> \n*/\n'
          },
          build: {
            files: {
              'dist/js/newMagic.min.js' : 'js/script/helloWorld.js'
//instead how to set dest/js : js/script/alljsfiles?
            }
          }
        }

    });

     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify'); //this is only one runs.
     grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch'); how to run both?


    };
```

my command: `grunt uglify`

Answer (score 0):

The most frequent use of uglify is to reduce many input files to one output file:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    banner: '/*\n <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> \n*/\n'
  },
  build: {
    files: [
      {
        "dist/js/newMagic.min.js": ["js/script/**/*.js"]
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

If you want to uglify many inputs to many outputs, you can do that with a file spec like this:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    banner: '/*\n <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> \n*/\n'
  },
  build: {
    files: [
      {
        src: ["**/*.js"],
        dest: "dist/js",
        cwd: "js/script",
        expand: true
      }
    ]
  },
}
```